# Can't design subview of my @IBDesignable view

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, subview, ibdesignable

I have the following:

```
@IBDesignable class CustomView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var hasFlag: Bool = true

    var flagView: UIView?

    override init(frame: frame) {

        super.init(frame)

        setup()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        setup()

    }

    func setup() {

        if (hasFlag) {

            flagView = UIView()

            flagView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            flagView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()


            addSubview(flagView!)

            flagView!.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(leadingAnchor, constant: 0).active = true

            flagView!.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topAnchor, constant: 0).active = true

            flagView!.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(8).active = true

            flagView!.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(bottomAnchor, constant: 0).active = true

        }

    }

}
```

However, when I go into interface builder, I see my red flag there but I don't have the option to select the flagView to, say, set its background color. Nor do I see it appear in the view hierarchy under my CustomView. I'm going to have multiple CustomViews, and each one might have a different color. I'd like to do this in interface builder rather than in code. Is there a way I can achieve editing my subview of my @IBDesignable through interface builder?

Comment: You have to create an IBInspectable property for each property you want to alter. UIViews already have this in IB though you shouldn't have to create your own.

Comment: I can alter all the normal UIView properties in interface builder for my CustomView, but I can't select my flagView in interface builder and edit its view properties. I tried `@IBInspectable var flag: UIView?` and `@IBDesignable var flag: UIView?` and neither worked.

Comment: Your subclassing UIView, in order to set the UIView in storyboard you name the class to `CustomView`. But you don't need to add IB properties since it's a subclass of UIView it already inherits that. My guess is your not adding a UIView to your storyboard and subclassing it to the CustomView class

Comment: Thanks for your comments. `CustomView` is not the view of which I want to change IB properties. `CustomView` itself has a UIView property `flagView` when `CustomView.hasFlag` is `true`. I want to change the IB properties of `flagView`. If you do exactly as you just told me to do and run my code you should see a subview of `CustomView` that has a red background. THAT'S the view I want to edit in IB, but can't.

Comment: Yes you got the answer, you cannot edit (via ib) the property of a view that is dynamically created by code at design time. The only way is make some ibinspectable variable in your custom class and apply them to the flag view one by one.....

Answer (score 0):

You can try "setup()" in layoutSubviews.

```
override func layoutSubviews() { 
     super.layoutSubviews()
     setup()
}
```